# Chain over iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Python script that controls a `list` of imaginary machines that have to walk above the lines of a given image.

I have a `Control` class that keeps track of all the instances of `Machine` and updates the instance's position and rotation. Due to some imperfections in the image, some instances can and will get lost so that they need to have their position "manually" recalculated.

The problem is that I need to apply a method in all the instances selected and returned in a `list` object without breaking the chain of function calls.

This is what I have:

```
class Control:
    def __init__(self, instances):
        self.machine_instances = instances
        ...

    def get(self, elem = 0, end = None, step = 1):
        return machine_instances[elem : end : step]

    ...


class Machine:
    def __init__(self, x_position):
        ...

    def position_recalc(self):
        ...

    ...
```

This is how it must be used:

```
ml = [Machine(int(sys.argv[i])) for i in range(1, sys.argc)]
c = Control(ml)

...

c.get(2, 4).position_recalc()
```

OBS: The method `Control.get()` may have its return value and type changed.

Comment: What is your question?  Is `get(2, 4)` supposed to return the machines at indices 2 and 4?

Comment: Simply do: `for machine in c.get(2, 4): machine.position_recalc()`. You may want to write a function that does that for your: `def recalc_all(control, *args): for machine in control.gets(*args): machine.position_recalc()`.

Comment: Can't I do it using `__getattr__`?

Comment: who is recalculating the indices - Control or Machine? it looks like Control...

Comment: btw, if you wanted to, you could implement `__getitem__` to allow doing something like Control[2:4] instead of Control.get(2,4).

Comment: @CorleyBrigman `Control` controls the indices of instances, but each instance must recalculate its properties (in this case position and rotation and not the index) by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to return something like a `list` with a `position_recalc` method

```
class ListWithReCalc(list):
    def position_recalc(self):
        ...

class Control:
    def __init__(self, instances):
        self.machine_instances = instances
        ...

    def get(self, elem = 0, end = None, step = 1):
        return ListWithReCalc(machine_instances[elem : end : step])
```

Otherwise you can use composition

```
class ThingWithReCalc(object):
    def __init__(self, items):
        self.items = items()

    def position_recalc(self):
        for i in self.items():
            i.position_recalc()

class Control:
    def __init__(self, instances):
        self.machine_instances = instances
        ...

    def get(self, elem = 0, end = None, step = 1):
        return ListWithReCalc(machine_instances[elem : end : step])
```

Comment: Isn't there a way I can add this method to built-in `list`?

Comment: @RodrigoSiqueira, no, this isn't Ruby. That's why the module is called [forbiddenfruit](http://clarete.github.io/forbiddenfruit/). Seriously you'd want _ALL_ of your list objects to have that method???

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class `SelectedMachines`:

```
class SelectedMachines:
    def __init__(self, selected):
        self.selected_machines = selected
    def position_recalc(self):
        for machine in self.selected_machines:
            machine.someFunction()
```

So you can return a SelectedMachines object in `Control.get()`:

```
class Control:
    def __init__(self, instances):
        self.machine_instances = instances
        ...

    def get(self, elem = 0, end = None, step = 1):
        return SelectedMachines(machine_instances[elem : end : step])

...
```

Where `someFunction()` is a method that applies recalculates position of one specific machine.

Comment: Yes that's the normal obvious way, but the question is insisting on a particular convention

Comment: @gnibbler Edited so it adjust to OP requirements.

Answer (score 0):

using a self return to simplify this a bit. this is one way to implement a modifiable interface:

```
class Control(object):
    def __init__(self, instances):
        self.focus = None
        self.instances = instances

    def get(self, start=None, end=None, slice=None):
        self.focus = (start, end, slice)
        return self

    def position_recalc(self):
        if self.focus == None:
            self.focus = (None, None, None)
        for i in self.instances.__getitem__(slice(*self.focus)):
            i.position_recalc()
        self.focus = None

c.get(2,4).position_recalc()
```

`c.get(2,4)` returns the same item, but sets a context for it, and returns the *same* object to the user, which is necessary so `position_recalc` has an object to work on. there's probably a general pattern for this (delegator?), this is an unusual form for it but still the same general pattern.